# Reading integers from a file and storing in an array

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream

I am currently trying to develop an understanding for reading data in general from a file, however in this case I am trying to read 7 integers from a txt file and store them in an array. The code I have so far is shown below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int arr[7];

    ifstream File;
    File.open("example.txt");

    for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++)
    {
        File >> arr[a];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

The output I'm getting from the debugger is shown below. I assume this was cause it simply couldn't open the file so I looked it up and found it the txt file should be placed in the working directory. I'm not sure exactly what this meant so I literally placed this in every folder in the project folder but I'm still getting the same errors. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Koolaid Lips\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[6584] Project2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Can i please get an explanation to the down votes?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code.  The window where you see those warnings about the PDB file is not where your program's output is displayed.  Try setting a breakpoint on the last `}` in `main`, which will prevent the console from closing before the program exits.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but what exactly is a breakpoint? You mean something like system("pause")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code the result is ok in Dev-C++ compiler.
Maybe you can change a compiler for your code.
Here is PDB file information,seem you can ignore the error messages.

> A program database (PDB) file holds debugging and project state information that allows incremental linking of a Debug configuration of your program. A PDB file is created when you compile a C/C++ program with /ZI or /Zi or a Visual Basic/C#/JScript .NET program with /debug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wasn't receiving any output because the terminal was closing so fast so I assumed there was something wrong with my code. Added a system("pause") so I could actually see it. Thanks again!

Comment: You can add `system ("PAUSE");` to check the result.